# error: expected type-specifier before 'Mobile'

Tags: c++

I did a research  but solution is not matching to my program. From the large code i took only erroneous part. Please suggest.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Products {

    static Products* prod;

public:
    //Creat a static funtion which does the task what client was doing
    static void checkStockStatus(int choice)
    {
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            prod = new Mobile();
            break;
        }
        prod->inStockStatus();
    }

    virtual void inStockStatus() = 0;
};

class Mobile : public Products {
public:
    void inStockStatus()
    {
        cout << "Mobiles are instock" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int choice = 1;
    Products::checkStockStatus(choice);
    return 0;
}
```

OutPut:
 In static member function 'static void Products::checkStockStatus(int)':
 14:29: error: expected type-specifier before 'Mobile'

Comment: Products doesn't know what a Mobile is, move the definition up.

Comment: Or you could forward declare it i.e `class Mobile;` above `class Products {`

Comment: @George You can't `new` an incomplete type.

Comment: @George I have tried forward declaration before posting it could not help..

Comment: @GillBates : Yes we cant `new` an incomplete type but we cant even define `class Mobile` before  `class Product` as `Mobile` is inheriting `Products`.